# AngularJS: Get the names of all binding within a certain element

Tags: javascript, angularjs, binding, two-way

Is there a way to get the name of an two-way-binding?

```
<div ng-controller="myController">
    <my-directive>
        {{abc}}
    </my-directive>
    <my-directive>
        {{def}}
    </my-directive>
</div>
```

Within the first my-directive element I would like to get the name 'abc'.